# Session variable in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Some time ago I created some simply login with session. It was a MVC app but with .net framework 4.6 if I'm correct. And I could there use something like

```
<h2>@Session["ID"]</h2>
```

And ID from session variable should be in h2 tag. But now I try to build same but with .net core 2.0.

My startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDbContext<L2Context>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite("Data Source=test.db"));

    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache
    services.AddSession(options => {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSession();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Controller to save data into session:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login(Users user)
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<L2Context>();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=test.db");

    using (L2Context db = new L2Context(optionsBuilder.Options))
    {
        var user = db.Users.Single(u => u.Login == user.Login && u.Password == user.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("ID", user.ID.ToString());
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Login", user.Login.ToString());
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoggedIn));
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login or password is invalid");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

LoggedIn View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "LoggedIn";
}

<h4> Hello @Session["Login"]</h4>
```

So, do I have some error here? I tough it was working last time when I used it.

I get:

> error CS0103: The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti While a good link, it doesn't show at all how to use it from a View...

Comment: @camilo it's explained just inside the "working with session state" section, pretty verbose but information is all there

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti will read it for sure. Let see what .net core can do :)

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Most of what you described with the user should be stored in the user principle which should hold the logged in user's claims.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, the View doesn't have access to the `Session` property of the `HttpContext` object by default. You can access it by importing the `Http` Namespace within the view:

```
//import the namespace to make the class available within the view
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
```

You can then access the `Session` property of the `HttpContext` object:

```
<h4> Hello @HttpContext.Session.GetString("Login")</h4>
```

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:
C:\Users\user\Dokumenty\L2\Views\Account\LoggedIn.cshtml(5,13): error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ISession'

But yea, propably it should work. Now need to figure why it didn't.

Comment: @Thou Fixed, sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of differences between .NET Core 2.0 and .NET 4.6. One of those is that in .NET Core 2.0, you don't have a Session property available. It is possible to get the session by using the HttpContext Context property.

This should work:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "LoggedIn";
}

<h4> Hello @Context.Session["Login"]</h4>
```

Comment: Like I said below, now I got error: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred: C:\Users\user\Dokumenty\L2\Views\Account\LoggedIn.cshtml(5,13): error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ISession'. .net core complicated life for me for sure :). But well, need to get used to.

Comment: "There are a couple of differences between .NET Core 2.0 and .NET 4.6", not sure how is that relevant. For ASP.NET Core, it doesn't matter if you choose one or the other

Comment: @Thou so just instead calling `.Session["Login"]` use `.Session.GetString("Login")`

Answer (score 1):

There is one more way of doing it. With it you don't need to muggle around the Session.
I am gonna tell you how I did it.

**Step 1**
Create a constant file, that we'll be using in our views later

```
using System;

namespace MyProject.CONSTANTS
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public static String USER_ENTITY
        {
            get
            {
                return "USER_ENTITY";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2**
Create an application level class `AppUser.cs` and and Interface for the same `IAppUser`

```
namespace MyProject.Configurations.Interface
{
    public interface IAppUser
    {
        UserDto UserEntity { get; }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace MyProject.Configurations
{
    public class AppUser : IAppUser
    {
        private IHttpContextAccessor httpContextProvider;

        public AppUser(IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextProvider)
        {
            httpContextProvider = _httpContextProvider;
        }

        public UserDto UserEntity
        {
            get
            {
                return httpContextProvider.HttpContext.Session.Get<UserDto>(Constants.USER_ENTITY);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3**
Now when you get data, store it as below

```
HttpContext.Session.Set(Constants.USER_ENTITY, result); //here result is type of `UserDto.cs` class
```

**What we've done above**

We stored our Session in constants, that we would use in views later with dependency injection.

**Step 4**
We have a shared view `_viewImports.cshtml` that has all the dependency injection in it.

We will inject our `IAppUser` interface in this view that is now accessible to all the views.

in `_viewImports.cshtml` do the followings  -

```
@using MyProject
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
@inject MyProject.Configurations.Interface.IAppUser AppUser  //AppUser is an aleas
```

Now in any view you now can use properties of `IAppUser` interface which is resolved with `AppUser.cs` class.

Say if `UserDto.cs` has a property as

```
public int ID {get;set;}
```

You can use it as - `@AppUser.UserEntity.ID`

That's all